# subsets in projective system

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{Z_i\}$ a directed projective system of quasi-compact topological spaces with projective limit $Z$. Assume we are given open subsets $U_i \subseteq Z_i$ such that:

1) For every $i \leq j$, the preimage $(Z_j \to Z_i)^{-1}(U_i)$ is contained in $U_j$.

2) For every $i$, the preimage $(Z \to Z_i)^{-1}(U_i)$ equals $Z$.

Does it follow that $U_i = Z_i$ for some $i$?

If not, assume that $\{Z_i\}$ is actually a system of affine schemes and scheme morphisms. Then it is true by (EGA IV, Corollaire 8.3.4). But I wonder if there is a direct proof which avoids all these nasty lemmas about ind-constructible sets ...

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.  For instance, let $X=[0,1]$ with the topology generated by the sets $[t,1]$ for each $t\in [0,1]$.  Let $Z_t=[t,1]\subseteq X$ for $t\in[0,1)$, with maps $Z_s\to Z_t$ for $s\geq t$ given by inclusion.  Each $Z_t$ is quasicompact, and their projective limit is just $\{1\}$.  Let $U_t=\{1\}$ for each $t$.  Then this satisfies your conditions, but $U_t\neq Z_t$ for all $t$.

Comment: Nice.thank you.I can't vote you because i need 15 points for that.vote me up 4 points.